# Google Charts 用のタグはどれがよい？

Tags: サポート, タグ

[Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/) 用にタグを作りたいです。

[google-charts](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-charts) という名前で良いかと思ったのですが、本家 Stack Overflow だと [[google-visualization]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-visualization/info) というタグで運用されており、[google-charts] は [google-visualization] への[シノニムとなっていました](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-visualization/synonyms)。また関連したタグとして [[google-chartwrapper]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-chartwrapper/info) というのもありました。

私は Google Charts にそこまで詳しくないので、どのタグ名が適切なのか分かりません。どのタグ名にするのが良いでしょうか？

Comment: 日本語圏ではGoogleChartsのほうが良く使われているような気がします。……ですがリファレンスに書いてあるAPIの正式名称っぽいのはGoogleVisualizationなんですよね。 https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference 個人的には本家に揃えるに一票。

Answer (score 2):

対比として改めて回答を書いておきます。

リファレンスに書いてあるAPIの正式名称は`GoogleVisualization`なので、
あくまでメインタグは [google-visualization] とし、
[google-charts] は [google-visualization] へのシノニムとして登録するように本家に揃えた方が良いと思います。

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference

Answer (score 0):

ストレートに[google-charts](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-charts)に一票。

タグ付けの際に(本家SOで使用されている) [google-visualization] や [google-chartwrapper] がソラで思い浮かぶかというと疑問です。なるべく足並みを揃えた方がよいという事であれば、同じシノニムを定義しておくのがよいのかもしれません。